# Powershell import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

Tags: powershell

So I am interested in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Namespace, cause in powershell we can read doc file via COM interface but I have a difficult task that needs doing without install Microsoft office.
Well how can I read doc file with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll?

```
[string]$assemblyPath = '.....\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll'
# Load assembly and suppress output
[void]([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($assemblyPath))
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($assemblyPath)
```

Comment: my understanding is that the MSWord app is far [far, far, far] more than just an assembly. it seems to REQUIRE that the app be _installed_ and that it be _run at least once by the account that tries to use it_. i do not think what you are trying to do will work.

Comment: You will need Microsoft Word installed and licensed`?` to be able to generate the COM interface for it.

Comment: Oh, okay Thanks guys )

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft Word COM, only if Word is installed on the computer.

You can consider using [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) Nuget Package